# ListView + OwnerData/OwnerDraw/VCL styles heavy flickering

Tags: listview, delphi, flicker, double-buffering

How can I avoid flickering on a custom drawn/data ListView? DoubleBuffering is already set but does not make any difference. Scrolling with the mouse wheel generates very noticeable flickering specially on the top and bottom of the LV, and using the scrollbar completely "blanks" it until you stop unless you move very slowly.

[image]

Code based on [RRUZ examples](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2017/03/09/tlistview-ownerdraw-compat-with-windows-ui-vcl-styles/).

DPR

```
program ListViewDemo;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {FrmMain},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Onyx Blue');
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmMain, FrmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

PAS

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  CommCtrl,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ComCtrls, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList, PngImageList;

type
  TColumnType = (ctText, ctCheck, ctProgress);

  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    LvSampleData: TListView;
    PngImageList1: TPngImageList;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LvSampleDataDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure LvSampleDataData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  private
    FColumns  : TDictionary<string, TListColumn>;
    procedure AddColumns();
    procedure AddItems();
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.GraphUtil;

procedure TFrmMain.AddColumns;

  Procedure AddColumn(const AColumnName : String; AWidth : Integer; AColumnType : TColumnType);
  begin
   FColumns.Add(AColumnName, LvSampleData.Columns.Add());
   FColumns[AColumnName].Caption := AColumnName;
   FColumns[AColumnName].Width   := AWidth;
   FColumns[AColumnName].Tag     := Integer(AColumnType);
  end;

begin
   FColumns  := TDictionary<string, TListColumn>.Create();
   AddColumn('Text', 150, ctText);
   AddColumn('Perc', 100, ctProgress);
   AddColumn('Text2', 150, ctText);
   AddColumn('Enabled', 100, ctCheck);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.AddItems;
const
 MaxItems = 100;
var
 LItem : TListItem;
 i : Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  LvSampleData.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to MaxItems - 1 do
    begin
      LItem := LvSampleData.Items.Add;
      LItem.Caption:= Format('Sample text', []);
      LItem.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Random(101)));
      LItem.SubItems.Add(Format('Sample text 2', []));
      LItem.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Random(2)));
    end;
  finally
    LvSampleData.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  LvSampleData.OwnerDraw := True;
  LvSampleData.OwnerData := True;
  LvSampleData.ViewStyle := TViewStyle.vsReport;
  AddColumns();
  LvSampleData.Items.Count := 200;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FColumns.Free;
end;

function ResizeRect(const ARect: TRect; const DxLeft, DxRight, DyTop, DyBottom: integer): TRect;
begin
  Result := ARect;
  Inc(Result.Left, DxLeft);
  Dec(Result.Right, DxRight);
  Inc(Result.Top, DyTop);
  Dec(Result.Bottom, DyBottom);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.LvSampleDataData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.ImageIndex := 0;
  Item.Caption := Format('Sample text '+IntToStr(Random(1000)), []);
  Item.SubItems.Add('75');
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('Sample text 2', []));
  Item.SubItems.Add('1');
end;

procedure TFrmMain.LvSampleDataDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const
  ListView_Padding = 5;
var
  LRect, LRect2: TRect;
  R: TRect;
  i, p : Integer;
  LText: string;
  LSize: TSize;
  LDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
  LTextFormat : TTextFormatFlags;
  LColor : TColor;
  LStyleService : TCustomStyleServices;
  LColummnType  : TColumnType;
begin

  LStyleService  := StyleServices;
  if not LStyleService.Enabled then exit;

  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := LStyleService.GetSystemColor(clWindow);
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  LRect := Rect;

  for i := 0 to TListView(Sender).Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    LColummnType := TColumnType(TListView(Sender).Columns[i].Tag);
    LRect.Right  := LRect.Left + Sender.Column[i].Width;

    LText := '';
    if i = 0 then
      LText := Item.Caption
    else
    if (i - 1) <= Item.SubItems.Count - 1 then
      LText := Item.SubItems[i - 1];

    Case LColummnType of
      ctText:  begin

                  LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tgCellNormal);
                  LColor := LStyleService.GetSystemColor(clWindowText);
                  if ([odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> []) then
                  begin
                     LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tgCellSelected);
                     LColor := LStyleService.GetSystemColor(clHighlightText);
                     LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect);
                  end;

                  LRect2 := LRect;
                  LRect2.Left := LRect2.Left + ListView_Padding + 16;

                  LTextFormat := TTextFormatFlags(DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
                  LStyleService.DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LText, LRect2, LTextFormat, LColor);
               end;

      ctCheck: begin
                  if ([odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> []) then
                  begin
                     LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tgCellSelected);
                     LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect);
                  end;

                  LSize.cx := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
                  LSize.cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUCHECK);

                  LRect2.Top    := Rect.Top + (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - LSize.cy) div 2;
                  LRect2.Bottom := LRect2.Top + LSize.cy;
                  LRect2.Left   := LRect.Left + ((LRect.Width - LSize.cx) div 2);
                  LRect2.Right  := LRect2.Left + LSize.cx;

                  if (LText = '1') then
                  begin
                    if ([odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> []) then
                      LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tbCheckBoxCheckedHot)
                    else
                      LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tbCheckBoxCheckedNormal);
                  end
                  else
                  begin
                    if ([odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> []) then
                      LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tbCheckBoxUncheckedHot)
                    else
                      LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tbCheckBoxUncheckedNormal);
                  end;
                  LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect2);
               end;


      ctProgress:
               begin
                  if ([odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> []) then
                  begin
                     LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tgCellSelected);
                     LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect);
                  end;

                  LRect2   := ResizeRect(LRect, 2, 2, 2, 2);
                  LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tpBar);
                  LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect2);

                  if not TryStrToInt(LText, p) then  p := 0;

                  InflateRect(LRect2, -1, -1);
                  LRect2.Right := LRect2.Left + Round(LRect2.Width * p / 100);

                  if p < 20 then
                  begin
                    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
                    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebFirebrick;
                    Sender.Canvas.FillRect(LRect2);
                  end
                  else
                  if p < 50 then
                  begin
                    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
                    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebGold;
                    Sender.Canvas.FillRect(LRect2);
                  end
                  else
                  begin
                    LDetails := LStyleService.GetElementDetails(tpChunk);
                    LStyleService.DrawElement(Sender.Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LRect2);
                  end;
                end;
    end;

    if i = 0 then begin
      ListView_GetItemRect(Sender.Handle, Item.Index, R, LVIR_ICON);
      ImageList_Draw(
          PngImageList1.Handle,
          0,
          Sender.Canvas.Handle,
          2,
          R.Top,
          ILD_TRANSPARENT);
    end;

    Inc(LRect.Left, Sender.Column[i].Width);
  end;
end;

end.
```

DFM

```
object FrmMain: TFrmMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Test'
  ClientHeight = 449
  ClientWidth = 731
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object LvSampleData: TListView
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 731
    Height = 449
    Align = alClient
    Columns = <>
    SmallImages = PngImageList1
    TabOrder = 0
    OnData = LvSampleDataData
    OnDrawItem = LvSampleDataDrawItem
  end
  object PngImageList1: TPngImageList
    PngImages = <
      item
        Background = clWindow
        Name = 'arrow-circle-double'
        PngImage.Data = {
          89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000001008060000001FF3FF
          610000001974455874536F6674776172650041646F626520496D616765526561
          647971C9653C000002724944415478DA7D925F4853511CC77FC76D2ED708525F
          8A302288B22C64230A56CD8885A3CCCCA21E7A18084E445BB45A3816A3A53559
          B81A3234C3A297516662A2FDDDD40C0277B5E8CF43105144F4A8A1C4DAEE6EDF
          33EF681BAB0B5FCE3DE7FE3E9FF3BBF71E4619570F721D792FCF5B19231B4605
          52B014038653C8B524D114422C9FC008B0350354FC856D6BDADB8F7C733AEFE3
          DECF25598211806532A0CC16ECE27099C753979C9BA382E262FAEA740E72494A
          D000B03107CC10ECE6F03AB7FBB00898156005F55CF2D9E97CC05E60A2CC03CA
          23874FAF77B96A13F3F3E0580A569494D027976B08CFBAFE27E0F0990D6D6D35
          BF6598EFAEC4CE1FDDEE613CBB8ABAC97F09F670B8DCE138184BB78D1402FEE0
          F13C441F3E0EF3FA7C020EDB2BECF603BF6498EFAE46DB6F3B3A46380CDD44BA
          3E5760C470B6D266332FF2B665B808F0ACD73B2A6C5675F6D66B26A637A98824
          8968319925E0F0397D4B4BF542FA8341B01C70D4E71BC3AC531F2A3D811A1D22
          40D09829A8C2A2634773F3FE9FBC6DF98369F1CEAFFCFEC7B31B55DE9BB54511
          74106D305B747DA3FD0289929E12524AC0E1F306ABD5148BC54814454A202B00
          4F05024FB0F315C38D95C77166F9CE74B4A65E776F7840489D3C89041661EC69
          E669DC69B1EC536B3434DEDDFD0CF0E5DBE665E17EB33A5A55B7574739576430
          2CB02EB4FB1A930AA45C9222D54D4DC6B160701C5FFA5288B1E7B74C85442675
          0F764B09B61CDBA67B77F7CD52070C1DC87F438B684244037CFD2551204014C6
          AD8824E58874513BB9FAE4DACAEF77BECCD08585ED7C9D0BF04F681552DA4714
          7C44D40BCBB40CC791843CC6E990CA8BCAADF4836668286EE5357F002DFCD337
          C469BD0A0000000049454E44AE426082}
      end>
    Left = 96
    Top = 88
    Bitmap = {}
  end
end
```

PNGImageList: https://github.com/TurboPack/PNGComponents

Comment: I see that you are using VCL styles. That could be a contributing factor.